# Detect last input in a line

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to build a better horse speed detector, that doesn't use gates/doors to stop you, but instead just has a row of pressure plates / trip wires

Is there a way I can detect which pressure plate in the row was triggered last, so i can turn on a light or something (but it turns off all the ones before it).

Comment: What do you mean by a "horse speed detector"?